# Can I add a variable to a cheerio selector?

Tags: javascript, node.js, screen-scraping, cheerio

I have a table that looks like this:

```
<table id="rounded-corner" class="sortable" style="width: 100%;">
<tbody>
<tr id="001" class="US">
<td>1
<td class="rare3">3★
<td sorttable_customkey="001"><a href="#001">
<div class="large" style="background-image: 
url('icons/servant/servant_0011.png'), 
</div></a>
<td sorttable_customkey="Mash Kyrielight">Name_of_character
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The table has over a hundred more rows, and every row is defined by tr id. So I wanted to select the only id I needed instead of selecting the whole table, but I don't know how to pass a variable to a cheerio selector.

I wanted to do something like this:

```
request(url, function(error, response, html) {
  if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    var fullTable = $('table[class="sortable"]');
    var tableRow = $(fulltable).find('td[id="variable_goes_here"]');
```

And from there I could scrape the data from the td tags I need.

Is there a way to place a variable inside find(), or do I need to parse the entire table to an array and the go look for the id?

Thank you!

Comment: `var tableRow = fulltable.find('#' + variable_goes_here);`

Comment: I managed to do it differently but this way also works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it using:

```
var fullTable = $('tr[id="'+variable_goes_here+'"]');
```

Thanks!